# Reuse brace pair in abolish.vim

Tags: plugin-vim-abolish

I want to replace all these at once:

```
Heading Name --> Another New Title
headingName  --> anotherNewTitle
```

I tried this:

:%S/heading{, }Name/another{, }New{, }Title/g

It replaces correctly including the first `{, }` brace pair on the replacement side, but the second one is substituted directly:

```
Heading Name --> Another New{, }Title
headingName  --> anotherNew{, }Title
```

Is there a way I can replace a space-separated string with a space separated string, while also replacing the camel cased version with its camel cased version?

I just found out I can use 'coercion' on a camel-cased word to turn it into a title-cased word, `crt` on `anotherNewTitle` would become `Another New Title`, but I would like a solution that uses only one substitution.

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a way to use another `{}` in the replacement portion of `:Subvert`

You can however accomplish this replacement:

```
:%S/heading{Name, Name}/another{TitleNew, Title New}/
```

It just isn't very satisfying and does not really save you much work.